# Bash script analyse apache log

Tags: linux, bash

I need help with this script
This script analyses apache_access.log through a filter.txt, if exist the term in filter the script will do something.
My problem i think is in the first command "for", I am not able to use the filter line by line.

can someone help me?

```
for term  in `tail -n $LINESTOSEARCH $IPEATERFILTER`
do
    for ip in `tail -n $LINESTOSEARCH $LOGFILE | grep "$TERM" | awk "{print \\$1}" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20 | awk "{if (\\$1 > $THRESHOLD) print \\$2}"`
    do
        # Look in iptables to see if this IP is already banned
        if ! iptables -L INPUT -n | grep -q $ip
        then



     # Do something



 fi

    done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [don't want to read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Use `while` and `read` instead. The problem is that the shell will split arguments on whitespace, so any space in the log file's line will actually cause the loop to run another time.

```
tail -n $LINESTOSEARCH $IPEATERFILTER | while read -r line; do
    # do something with "$line"
done
```

Repeat the same pattern for inner loops.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Your command only read the first line in filter.